# bash:Syntax near unexpected error '('

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I am following a tutorial in computational microbiology:

- William Lindstrom, Garrett M. Morris, Christoph Weber, and Ruth Huey (2008-01-29). *[Using AutoDock 4 for Virtual Screening](http://autodock.scripps.edu/faqs-help/tutorial/using-autodock4-for-virtual-screening/UsingAutoDock4forVirtualScreening_v4.pdf)*.  Scripps Research Institute.

On page 10 there is `ex01.csh` which contains (original unindented, indentation added by StackExchange participants):

```
foreach f (tmp*)
  echo $f
  set zid = `grep ZINC $f`
  if !(-e "$zid".mol2) then
     set filename = "$zid".mol2
  else foreach n (`seq –w 1 99`)
    if !(-e "$zid"_"$n".mol2) then
      set filename = "$zid"_"$n".mol2
      break
    endif
   end
   endif
   mv –v $f $filename
end
```

I want to run the above command.  I have been trying to figure it out for the last 2 days but have failed. Every time, at the first step, which is

```
foreach f (tmp*)
```

it says

```
bash : syntax near unexpected error '('
```

I know zero about linux stuff, and am just following what I see in the tutorial. 
How i can fix my problem?

Comment: I edit your code tu put some indentation, you tag as bash; but this look csh to me, how do you call the script ? `csh shell` ?

Comment: That isn't bash code. What tutorial are you following? If you are new to Linux, stop following this tutorial now. Run away. Do not, I repeat not, start learning csh as your first shell.

Comment: @terdon While I agree with you about `csh` being unsuitable for shell scripting, `csh` and `tcsh` can perfectly ok as interactive shells <opinion>.

Comment: @Kusalananda sure they can. However, a new user coming in to the Linux (not even Unix) world in 2016 would really be much better served by learning one of the sh family of shells instead of csh. Some form of bourne shell is always installed on Linux, and basic knowledge of it is needed for certain admin tasks. It doesn't make sense to start off with another shell as a new user.

Comment: @terdon Agrees I do.

Comment: Crossposted here http://askubuntu.com/questions/795772/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token

Comment: `csh` is no good for scripting (including one-liners), so you have to learn a `sh` dialect for scripting anyway. - you may as well just use bash or zsh or ksh.  and csh's interactive features have long since been surpassed by bash + zsh + ksh (and others), so there's not even any benefit for a new user to start using (and not much benefit for a long-time user to keep using it).

Comment: steeldriver has pointed to a duplicate, which provided context for finding the actual tutorial.  The questioner isn't trying to learn shell scripting from a shell scripting tutorial.  The questioner is trying to learn how to do computational microbiology with Unix/Linux tools from a tutorial on doing _that_.

Comment: [please don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/310919)

Answer (score 2):

As @Archemar correctly points out, this is a cshell script, it is not to be run in the default Linux shell.

If in Debian do:

```
apt-get install tcsh
```

And add as first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: if you're going to install `csh`, at least install the `tcsh` version.  it's still not worth using but at least it fixes some of the worst problems.

Comment: The original script in the actual tutorial has `#!/bin/csh` as its first line already, note.

Comment: @JdeBP No comments...

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial that you quote is using the `csh` shell throughout, but you are trying to execute it using the `bash` shell (it's obvious from the error message you get).

The two shells have a very different syntax and can't be used interchangeably to run a script. Think of them as two separate programming languages.

- Make sure that the script has `#!/bin/csh` as its first line (and nothing else after that, I spotted one script in the tutorial with a comment immediately on the same line, which is wrong).
- Make sure that the script is executable by issuing the command `chmod +x script.csh` (where `script.csh` is the name of the file containing the script).
- Run the script with `./script.csh`.

Alternatively:

- Run the script by giving the interpreter explicitly with `csh script.csh`.

Obviously, if `csh` is not installed on your system, you have to deal with that first. This is done in different ways depending on the package manager used by your Unix.

It is fairly uncommon to see shell scripts written for `csh` nowadays, especially on the free Unices, after most have switched their default setup to either `bash`, some `ksh`-variant or to some other `sh`-compatible shell.

There's a text written by Tom Christiansen (Perl guy) in 1994 that I used to see referenced much more frequently a few years ago, but not very often nowadays (probably because many users simply don't know about the *existence* of anything other than a `sh`-compatible shell).  It bears the title "[CSH PROGRAMMING CONSIDERED HARMFUL](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)".

Comment: +1 for the important ["CSH PROGRAMMING CONSIDERED HARMFUL"](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) link.